# Serenity method to save a network response value for use in next step of test

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, serenity

I am trying to take an ID string value that is generated in the network response log after the webapp hits an API and generates an object. The object has an ID value that is present in the network > response log and I need to copy it so I can use the value in other test steps.

[the network response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI0Bb.png)

Essentially, these are the steps I am automating

```
Then Click the submit button
And Save the [object ID value] that is generated
Then search for the [object ID value] in the home page search bar.
```

I have tried to search for ways to copy values from the network log but the responses I've found seem to be too complex for what I need to do.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you're saying. This is my first post on SO and I am not allowed to embed images in my posts yet.